# expression appends comma to the end of every line. Should not do the last line though

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pattern which works well for adding a comma to the end of every line.

```
str.replace(/(.+)\s*?($|\n)/gm, "$1, $2")
```

But I cannot understand how to change it so that it will not put a comma on the last line. Especially considering the last line could end in a line break. I guess I could search for the comma after the replace is done and just remove the last comma, but that seems sort of weak. Is there some way I can change this pattern so that it never appends a comma to the last line?

Comment: Try and drop the `$|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `$` from there, and add it as negative look ahead after `\n`:

```
str.replace(/(.+)\s*?(\n(?!$))/gm, "$1, $2")
```

This will only add a comma before `\n` if it is not at the end of the string.

Comment: That still gives me `1\n2\n3\n` => `1,\n2,\3,\n` (encoded my line breaks so you could see where they are after the replace. Thank you though!

Comment: This is wonderful, Thank you! What does the `?!$` construct do though?

Comment: @thomas. It's negative look ahead. It will match the `\n` only if it is not followed by `$`, that is end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not think in a bit different and very easy :

\r?\n(.+)